# PHP regex crashing apache

Tags: php, regex, windows, apache

I've got a regex that does matching for a template system, which unfortunately seems to crash apache (it's running on Windows) on some modestly-trivial lookups.  I've researched the issue and there are a few suggestions for upping stack size etc, none of which seem to work and I don't really like dealing with such issues by upping limits anyway as it generally just pushed the bug into the future.

Anyway any ideas on how to alter the regex to make it less likely to foul up?

The idea is to catch the innermost block (in this case `{block:test}This should be caught first!{/block:test}`) which I'll then str_replace out the starting/ending tags and re-run the whole thing through the regex until there are no blocks left.

Regex:

```
~(?P<opening>{(?P<inverse>[!])?block:(?P<name>[a-z0-9\s_-]+)})(?P<contents>(?:(?!{/?block:[0-9a-z-_]+}).)*)(?P<closing>{/block:\3})~ism
```

Sample template:

```
<div class="f_sponsors s_banners">
    <div class="s_previous">&laquo;</div>
    <div class="s_sponsors">
        <ul>
            {block:sponsors}
            <li>
                <a href="{var:url}" target="_blank">
                    <img src="image/160x126/{var:image}" alt="{var:name}" title="{var:name}" />
                </a>
            {block:test}This should be caught first!{/block:test}
            </li>
            {/block:sponsors}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="s_next">&raquo;</div>
</div>
```

It's a long shot I suppose.  :(

Comment: Weird as it sounds, I once had a regex that kept eating one particular Apache instance and the `S` (*upper case!*) flag fixed it. I guessed it was an unreported memory leak or something and the study process caused it to be avoided. Long shot but worth a try, I would say...

Comment: @DaveRandom, I had the same issue once, with the same fix! Lets see if that does it for the OP

Comment: Another thought that occurs is that escaping the literal `{}` characters in the regex might help. They are technically meta characters and while PCRE does seem to be quite forgiving of unescaped curly braces, it might give it less work to do if you escape them properly. Also why use named capture groups and not use the names in back references? `/block:\3` => `/block:(?P=name)`. This especially true for your regex since `<inverse>` is optional in which case `<name>` will be `\2`, not `\3`

Comment: Do you mean on the ~ism section for the s flag? As it doesn't work if the closing tag is on a different line than the opening tag without the s?  Good catch on the back reference name though.

Comment: Just to say thanks to everyone for their help on this so far!

Comment: In my opinion, you will have much easier time if you used a pattern like `\{/?block:(\w+)\}` (for example - but with some more groups), and use regex for lexical analysis, but not for full parsing. You can then match the proper start/end tags in your code, which I suspect would be much easier. This can also free you from the need to replace iteratively - you would be able to do it in a single scan. Just a thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
'~(?P<opening>\{(?P<inverse>[!])?block:(?P<name>[a-z0-9\s_-]+)\})(?P<contents>[^{]*(?:\{(?!/block:(?P=name)\})[^{]*)*)(?P<closing>\{/block:(?P=name)\})~i'
```

Or, in readable form:

```
'~(?P<opening>
  \{
  (?P<inverse>[!])?
  block:
  (?P<name>[a-z0-9\s_-]+)
  \}
)
(?P<contents>
  [^{]*(?:\{(?!/block:(?P=name)\})[^{]*)*
)
(?P<closing>
  \{
  /block:(?P=name)
  \}
)~ix'
```

The most important part is in the `(?P<contents>..)` group:

```
[^{]*(?:\{(?!/block:(?P=name)\})[^{]*)*
```

Starting out, the only character we're interested in is the opening brace, so we can slurp up any other characters with `[^{]*`.  Only after we see a `{` do we check to see if it's the beginning of a `{/block}` tag.  If it isn't, we go ahead and consume it and start  scanning for the next one, and repeat as necessary.

Using RegexBuddy, I tested each regex by placing the cursor at the beginning of the `{block:sponsors}` tag and debugging.  Then I removed the ending brace from the closing `{/block:sponsors}` tag to force a failed match and debugged it again.  Your regex took 940 step to succeed and  2265 steps to fail.  Mine took 57 steps to succeed and 83 steps to fail.

On a side note, I removed the `s` modifier because because I'm not using the dot (`.`), and the `m` modifier because it never was needed.  I also used the named backreference  `(?P=name)` instead of `\3` as per @DaveRandom's excellent suggestion.  And I escaped all the braces (`{` and `}`) because I find it easier to read that way.

---

**EDIT:** If you want to match the *innermost* named block, change the middle portion of the regex from this:

```
(?P<contents>
  [^{]*(?:\{(?!/block:(?P=name)\})[^{]*)*
)
```

...to this (as suggested by @Kobi in his comment):

```
(?P<contents>
  [^{]*(?:\{(?!/?block:[a-z0-9\s_-]+\})[^{]*)*
)
```

Originally, the `(?P<opening>...)` group would grab the first opening tag it saw, then the `(?P<contents>..)` group would consume anything--including other tags--as long as they weren't the closing tag to match the one found by the `(?P<opening>...)` group.  (Then the `(?P<closing>...)` group would go ahead and consume that.)

Now, the `(?P<contents>...)` group refuses to match *any* tag, opening or closing (note the `/?` at the beginning), no matter what the name is.  So the regex initially starts to match the `{block:sponsors}` tag, but when it encounters the `{block:test}` tag, it abandons that match and goes back to searching for an opening tag.  It starts again at the `{block:test}` tag, this time successfully completing the match when it finds the `{/block:test}` closing tag.

It sounds inefficient describing it like this, but it's really not.  The trick I described earlier, slurping up the non-braces, drowns out the effect of these false starts.  Where you were doing a negative lookahead at almost every position, now you're doing one only when you encounter a `{`.  You could even use possessive quantifiers, as as @godspeedlee suggested:

```
(?P<contents>
  [^{]*+(?:\{(?!/?block:[a-z0-9\s_-]+\})[^{]*+)*+
)
```

...because you know it will never consume anything that it will have to give back later.  That would speed things up a little, but it isn't really necessary.

Comment: I've updated the question a bit as it only ever catches the outermost block. however yours still doesn't require the ~sm portion so I think it's on the right track!

Comment: Very nice! I *think* I understand what the OP wants... I think by "nested block" they mean nested blocks of any name, not just of the same name, that are replaced iteratively. so `{1} {2} {/2} {/1}` should capture `2` before `1`. If that is the case, you can easily change the middle part, from `[^{]*(?:\{(?!/block:(?P=name)\})[^{]*)*` to `[^{]*(?:\{(?!/?block:[a-z0-9\s_-]+\})[^{]*)*` - http://regexr.com?31qsf

Comment: Similar issue matching HTML <select>: `#<select(?:\s[^>]*)?>(?:(?!</select>).)*</select>#s` crashed whereas `#<select(?:\s[^>]*)?>[^<]*(?:<(?!/select>)[^<]*)*</select>#s` worked.  Though adding `U` ungreedy modifier also prevented crash; I'm not sure why as I thought that caused more backtracking and inefficiency - if not, I may as well have just written `#<select(?:\s.*)?>.*</select>#Us` and be done with it...

Answer (score 4):

You could use `atomic group: (?>...)` or `possessive quantifiers: ?+ *+ ++..` to suppress/limit the backtracking and speed up matching by `unrolling loop` technique. My solution:

`\{block:(\w++)\}([^<{]++(?:(?!\{\/?block:\1\b)[<{][^<{]*+)*+)\{/block:\1\}`

I have tested from http://regexr.com?31p03.

match `{block:sponsors}...{/block:sponsors}`:
`\{block:(sponsors)\}([^<{]++(?:(?!\{\/?block:\1\b)[<{][^<{]*+)*+)\{/block:\1\}`
http://regexr.com?31rb3

match `{block:test}...{/block:test}`:
`\{block:(test)\}([^<{]++(?:(?!\{\/?block:\1\b)[<{][^<{]*+)*+)\{/block:\1\}`
http://regexr.com?31rb6

the other solution:
in PCRE source code, you can remove the comment from `config.h`:
`/* #undef NO_RECURSE */`

following text copy from `config.h`:
PCRE uses recursive function calls to handle backtracking while matching. This can sometimes be a problem on systems that have stacks of limited size.
Define NO_RECURSE to get a version that doesn't use recursion in the match() function; instead it creates its own stack by steam using pcre_recurse_malloc() to obtain memory from the heap.

or you could change `pcre.backtrack_limit` and `pcre.recursion_limit` from `php.ini` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php)

Comment: However when you put a block within a block it only catches the outermost block, rather than the innermost block.  I've updated the question somewhat!

Answer (score 4):

Does the solution have to be a single regular expression? A more efficient approach might be simply to look for the first occurrence of `{/block:` (which could be a simple string search or a regex) and then search backwards from that point to find its matching opening tag, replace the span appropriately and repeat until there are no more blocks. If every time round you look for the *first* closing tag starting from the top of the template then that will give you the most deeply nested block.

The mirror image algorithm would work just as well - look for the last opening tag and then search forward from there for the corresponding closing tag:

```
<?php

$template = //...

while(true) {
  $last_open_tag = strrpos($template, '{block:');
  $last_inverted_tag = strrpos($template, '{!block:');
  // $block_start is the index of the '{' of the last opening block tag in the
  // template, or false if there are no more block tags left
  $block_start = max($last_open_tag, $last_inverted_tag);
  if($block_start === false) {
    // all done
    break;
  } else {
    // extract the block name (the foo in {block:foo}) - from the character
    // after the next : to the character before the next }, inclusive
    $block_name_start = strpos($template, ':', $block_start) + 1;
    $block_name = substr($template, $block_name_start,
        strcspn($template, '}', $block_name_start));

    // we now have the start tag and the block name, next find the end tag.
    // $block_end is the index of the '{' of the next closing block tag after
    // $block_start.  If this doesn't match the opening tag something is wrong.
    $block_end = strpos($template, '{/block:', $block_start);
    if(strpos($template, $block_name.'}', $block_end + 8) !== $block_end + 8) {
      // non-matching tag
      print("Non-matching tag found\n");
      break;
    } else {
      // now we have found the innermost block
      // - its start tag begins at $block_start
      // - its content begins at
      //   (strpos($template, '}', $block_start) + 1)
      // - its content ends at $block_end
      // - its end tag ends at ($block_end + strlen($block_name) + 9)
      //   [9 being the length of '{/block:' plus '}']
      // - the start tag was inverted iff $block_start === $last_inverted_tag
      $template = // do whatever you need to do to replace the template
    }
  }
}

echo $template;
```